# ListView built with SceneBuilder8 does not show inserted list

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am attempting to create a GUI for the front end of a program that will be used in my office. I have been tasked to use Scene Builder 8 to help create said GUI. This is my first project using JavaFX and Scene Builder so I've had to learn everything from scratch. My problem is that the while the code isn't throwing me any errors, I cannot see the sample data that I've put into the program. It's making me question the program as a whole.

If some of the following code looks superfluous to you, it may be because development for the backend part of the program is happening at the same time by a different person.

Here is the Mainapp:

```
package simit.gui;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import simit.gui.launch.model.LocalLaunch;
import simit.gui.launch.model.TextAreaOutputStream;
import simit.gui.launch.view.CompleteList;
import simit.gui.launch.view.LocalLaunchController;
import simit.gui.launch.view.MonitorController;


public class Main extends Application {
    //Hold onto the main state
    Stage primaryStage;

    private ObservableList<simit.gui.launch.view.CompleteList> listData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 

    public Main(){
        listData.add(new CompleteList("sample1"));
        listData.add(new CompleteList("sample2"));
    }

    public ObservableList<CompleteList> getListData(){
        return listData;
    }

    //Run simulation
    public void runSimulation(File inputDeck, int procs, int mem){

        try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("launch/view/Monitor.fxml"));
        AnchorPane rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        //Get the controller
        MonitorController controller = loader.getController();

        //Setup the view
        List<TextAreaOutputStream> textAreas = controller.SetUpTextAreas(procs);



        //Try to launch the code
        LocalLaunch launch  = new LocalLaunch(inputDeck, procs, mem, textAreas);

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
//      try {
//          BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
//          Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
//          scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
//          primaryStage.setScene(scene);
//          primaryStage.show();
//      } catch(Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }

         try {
                // Load root layout from fxml file.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("launch/view/LocalLaunch.fxml"));
                AnchorPane rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

                // Show the scene containing the root layout.
                Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();

                //Load up the LocalLaunch Controller
                LocalLaunchController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.SetMain(this);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the FXML Controller:

```
package simit.gui.launch.view;

import java.io.File;

import org.controlsfx.control.CheckListView;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import simit.gui.Main;
import simit.gui.launch.model.LocalLaunch;

public class LocalLaunchController {

    //Hold onto the required text fields
    @FXML
    private TextField path;

    @FXML
    private TextField procs;

    @FXML
    private TextField mem;

    final ObservableList<CompleteList> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    final public CheckListView<CompleteList> listItems = new CheckListView<CompleteList>();


    private Main mainProgram;



    public void SetMain(Main mainProgram){
        this.mainProgram = mainProgram;
        items.addAll(mainProgram.getListData());
        listItems.setItems(items);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleSelect() {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
         fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
         fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                 new ExtensionFilter("SMT File", "*"+LocalLaunch.PaserExt),
                 new ExtensionFilter("Resume File", "*"+LocalLaunch.RsmExp),
                 new ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*"));
         File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
         if (selectedFile != null) {
            path.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
         }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleRun() {
        //Make sure input is valid
        if(!isInputValid())
            return;

        //Get the data
        File tmpFile = new File(path.getText());
        int proc = Integer.parseInt(procs.getText());
        int mem = Integer.parseInt(this.mem.getText());

        mainProgram.runSimulation(tmpFile, proc, mem);
    }

       /**
     * Validates the user input in the text fields.
     * 
     * @return true if the input is valid
     */
    private boolean isInputValid() {
        String errorMessage = "";

        if(path.getText().isEmpty()){
            errorMessage += "The input deck cannot be empty!\n"; 
        }

        //Create a test file
        File testFile = new File(path.getText());
        if(!testFile.exists())
            errorMessage += "The input deck must exisit!\n"; 

        if (procs.getText() == null || procs.getText().length() == 0) {
            errorMessage += "No valid procs specified!\n"; 
        } else {
            // try to parse the postal code into an int.
            try {
                int p =Integer.parseInt(procs.getText());
                if(p <= 0)
                    throw new NumberFormatException();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                errorMessage += "No valid procs specified (must be a positive integer)!\n"; 
            }
        }
        if (mem.getText() == null || mem.getText().length() == 0) {
            errorMessage += "No valid mem specified!\n"; 
        } else {
            // try to parse the postal code into an int.
            try {
                int p =Integer.parseInt(mem.getText());
                if(p <= 0)
                    throw new NumberFormatException();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                errorMessage += "No valid mem specified (must be a positive integer)!\n"; 
            }
        }


        if (errorMessage.length() == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // Show the error message.
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Invalid Fields");
            alert.setHeaderText("Please correct invalid fields");
            alert.setContentText(errorMessage);

            alert.showAndWait();

            return false;
        }
    }


    @FXML
    private void initialize() {  
    }
}
```

Here is a class I've made for the input variable:

```
package simit.gui.launch.view;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class CompleteList {

    private final StringProperty listDetails;

    public CompleteList(){
        this(null);
    }
    public CompleteList(String listDetails){
        this.listDetails = new SimpleStringProperty(listDetails);
    }
    public String getListDetails() {
        return listDetails.get();
    }
    public void setListDetails(String listDetails) {
           this.listDetails.set(listDetails);
       }
    public StringProperty listDetailsProperty(){
        return listDetails;
    }

}
```

And finally here is the FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import org.controlsfx.control.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="simit.gui.launch.view.LocalLaunchController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" layoutX="120.0" layoutY="41.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="400.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
            <ImageView fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" smooth="false">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../resources/SIMITBlastLogo.png" />
               </image>
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
               </cursor>
            </ImageView>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
               <children>
                  <GridPane layoutX="50.0" layoutY="58.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="20.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Input Deck">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin></Label>
                        <Label text="Processors" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin></Label>
                        <TextField fx:id="procs" text="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <TextField fx:id="path" editable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <Button alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSelect" text="Select" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets />
                           </GridPane.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Label text="Mem/Proc" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                           <GridPane.margin>
                              <Insets left="10.0" />
                           </GridPane.margin></Label>
                        <Label text="GB" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <TextField fx:id="mem" promptText="1" text="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <ButtonBar layoutX="129.0" layoutY="248.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0">
                    <buttons>
                      <Button defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleRun" text="Run Simulation" />
                    </buttons>
                  </ButtonBar>
                  <CheckListView fx:id="listItems" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="117.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is what I'm seeing when I run the program (minus the image on top, I've gotten rid of it for a little anonymity):

[Image of the program when ran.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DkZT.png)

What I need to see is list items populating that white square in the middle.

Any help anyone can give me at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml) (Since passing the data) BTW: Only assigning a list as items of a `ListView` and then never touching `ListView` or list again won't make it populate miraculously.

Comment: I.e. you do `listItems.setItems(list);` in the `initialize()` method, but at no point anywhere in your code do you put anything into `list`.

Comment: I've done what James_D told me and now the variables actually point to data, but I still have a big blank white square sadly.